# Using flexible SliverAppBar as non-top element

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to display a flexible SliverAppBar below a custom app bar (let's say it's a container with a height of 80.0).

When making the SliverAppBar the top element, it works fine, but when it's the second one, there is a top-padding as big as the Android UI interface.

```
 Scaffold(
   body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 80.0),
          Expanded(child: _content())
        ]),
 );
```

**_content()**

```
return CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
  SliverAppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    leading: PopContentButton(),
    title: Text('Test'),
    snap: true,
    pinned: true,
    floating: true,
    bottom: TabBar(
      tabs: _tabs(),
      controller: TabControllerExtended(length: 4, vsync: this),
    ),
  ),
  SliverList(delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(buildTextViews(50)))
]);
```

This is not how it should look:
[image: wrong]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/2d3da1-1546592690.jpg))</sub>

It should look like:
[image: right]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/ba90e0-1546592864.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you - `SliverAppBar` with  `MediaQuery.removePadding`.

Updated Code :

```
....
MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        child: SliverAppBar(
...
```